# Has Alpha Centauri been a subject for SETI activities?

Tags: seti, alpha-centauri

There is a claim that habitable-zone orbits are stable around both components of the Alpha Centauri binary, and at least one planet has been detected (though not in the habitable zone). Both stars appear to be about as old as the Sun or older. There is now some serious effort to look for an "Earth Proxima" ([Mission Centaur](http://missioncentaur.org/project/)) in the Alpha Centauri system. Seems like a lot more to go on than [SETI](http://www.seti.org/) has had with other places they've been listening to. With that in mind, has there ever been any effort to listen for artificial signals from Alpha Centauri or to send something like an "Arecibo message"?

Since Alpha Centauri is only about 4 light years away, it would be reasonable to expect that *if* there is an intelligence present with the means and desire to listen and reply (admittedly a whole lot of "ifs"), we shouldn't have to wait more than 10 years to get a result if one is at all forthcoming, and it would be a relatively inexpensive exercise to undertake, even if nothing comes of it.

Comment: Have you seen this: http://www.seti.org/weeky-lecture/checking-neighbors-searching-planets-around-alpha-centauri ? I can't watch right now, but it looks promising.

Comment: Though an official announcement isn't expected until late August, it [now appears](http://www.universetoday.com/130276/earth-like-planet-around-proxima-centauri-discovered/#) that there's an Earth-like planet orbiting *Proxima* Centauri. Proxima is about 0.24 light-years from Alpha Centauri A and B, with a separation as seen from Earth of 2.18°. Proxima is a flare star, which might limit the possibilities for life.

Comment: @KeithThompson I was watching some of the SETI videos at/associated with the link mentioned above. Proxima is apparently a very un-promising candidate for life.

Comment: The videos predate the recent discovery. But yes, the x-ray flares could be a bit of an inconvenience. It's also worth mentioning that studies aimed at Alpha Centauri A and B likely wouldn't cover Proxima.

Answer (score 5):

[Yes](http://physicsdatabase.com/2015/11/21/seti-searching-for-planets-in-alpha-centauri/), SETI [has listened](http://io9.gizmodo.com/5952357/scientists-discover-a-planet-in-alpha-centauri-the-star-system-nearest-earth) to Alpha Centauri. [Here's a 2003 list of targets](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/379320/fulltext/) for SETI, which includes all of the 100 closest stars.

Comment: Considering the recent news about *Proxima* Centari (possibly) having a rocky planet in the habitable region - I wonder if this question and answer should just be updated to include both stars. They are both #1 in the list in your link - I think because Alpha CEN and [Proxima CEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxima_Centauri) are physically close together and within the beam width of the measurement. I was about to ask the question about Proxima when i found this - no need for a separate question?